# Show that a vector line integral is equal to $2\pi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $S$ be the region in the plane between the circle of radius $2$ (with center at $(0,0)$ and the square with vertices $(1,1),(-1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1)$.
Let $\textbf{G}$ be the vector field in the plane defined by:
$$\textbf{G}(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\textbf{i}+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\textbf{j}$$

And lastly, let $C^+$ be any simple closed smooth curve $C$ in $S$ oriented counterclockwise so that it encapsulates the square.

Show that:
$$\int_{C^+}\textbf{G}\cdot dl=2\pi$$

I found that $\textbf{G}$ is a conservative vector field with $f=-\arctan(\frac{x}{y})$, so I figured the solution would be something like this:

$$\int_{C^+}\textbf{G}\cdot dl=f(B)-f(A)$$

where $A$ and $B$ are the initial and terminal points of $C^+$, but because $C^+$ is closed this would equal $0$.

How can I progress with this exercise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\mathbf G$ is *not* conservative. Your alleged potential function is only defined on $y\ne 0$. Compute the line integral around the circle *explicitly* (by parametrizing), and then apply Green's Theorem to the region between your curve and that circle.